# RGBA — Alpha channel as a separate class

Tags: css

Let's say we have a list of classes storing background colors.

```
.bgr-red //background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
.bgr-green //background-color: rgb(0, 0 , 255);
.bgr-blue //background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);
```

And we have a div using one of these classes.

```
<div class="bgr-red">...</div>
```

Is there any way that I can create a new set of classes which contain alpha channels? Something like this (I tried this method, it didn't work):

```
.alpha-90 //background-color: rgba(inherit, inherit, inherit, .9);
.alpha-80 //background-color: rgba(inherit, inherit, inherit, .8);
.alpha-70 //background-color: rgba(inherit, inherit, inherit, .7);
```

The end objective being to be able to place background color opacity into a div separate from the rest of the background color value? Creative a div something like this:

```
<div class="bgr-red alpha-80">...</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `rgba(inherit, inherit, inherit, .9);` strange, if you need everything inherited why don't just use `opacity`?

Comment: @BladeMight because opacity will also affect content inside

Comment: okay. I got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CSS variables:

```css
.bgr-red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, var(--a, 1));
}

.bgr-green {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, var(--a, 1));
}

.bgr-blue {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, var(--a, 1));
}

.alpha-90 {
  --a: 0.9;
}

.alpha-70 {
  --a: 0.7;
}

.alpha-10 {
  --a: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgr-red">...</div>

<div class="bgr-red alpha-70">...</div>

<div class="bgr-red alpha-10">...</div>
```

And for better support you can consider pseudo element to create the background layer and adjust opacity:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bgr-red::before {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.bgr-green::before {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.bgr-blue::before {
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);
}

.alpha-90::before {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.alpha-70::before {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.alpha-10::before {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgr-red">...</div>

<div class="bgr-red alpha-70">...</div>

<div class="bgr-red alpha-10">...</div>
```