# Can I use CSS variables in a font list and have it work in legacy browsers?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I'd like to use a CSS variable to store a font in case the user doesn't have the specified font installed.

Example:

```
:root {
     --common-font: Comic Sans MS;
}

.header1 {
     font-family: CoolFont1, var(--common-font);
}
```

Will legacy browsers break if I add a reference to the variable in the font names?

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: I wasn't aware of that css feature, so thanks for introducing it. :-)

Comment: Anyway, I think you would be better of using less or sass. Then you can use variables without any problems; your less/sass will be converted to css and it will work in all browsers. It's very easy to learn (it's like css with variables and functions).

Comment: @johey LESS/SASS will not replace CSS variable, they don't have the same purpose

Comment: @temani-afif Less/sass support variables (cf. http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature / https://sass-lang.com/guide). That is serving the same purpose as css variables, no?

Comment: @johey LESS/SASS are preprocessor in order to generate CSS code, so the variable used there aren't at the CSS level unlike CSS variable that are available within the CSS code and that we can manipulate with JS and other CSS, etc ... so no, they aren't the same

Comment: @temani-afif Maybe css variables indeed offer some extra functionalities (like external manipulation - I wonder what could be the use of that though), but in this case those are not needed. For this use case a css preprocessor really looks the way to go. More on this debate here: https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/

Comment: @johey I am not debating if in this case they are useful or not or what it's better. I simply highlight the fact that the LESS/SASS variables aren't the same as CSS variables. Which one is better remain opinion based. And in case you want some use cases here is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750566/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/53239880/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851246/8620333 (and many more)

Comment: @temani-afif Wow, that indeed looks very powerful. Thanks for the info. :-)

Comment: @johey please don't serial upvote :), it can be bad for you. The system will detect this as supicious and will remove them

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it will break, you must use fallback font for legacy browser without using CSS variables.

For example:

```
   .header {
       font-family: sans-serif; /* This is fallback font for old browsers */
       font-family: var(--common-font);
    }
```

Also you can use a [@supports condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) with a dummy feature query:

```
.header {
    @supports ( (--a: 0)) {
      /* supported */
      font-family: var(--common-font);
    }

    @supports ( not (--a: 0)) {
      /* not supported */
      font-family: sans-serif; /* This is fallback font for old browsers */
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably add how to use a fallback to make the answer complete

Comment: Why is this not an answer? The question was "Will legacy browsers break if I add a reference to the variable in the font names?". Answer here: "Yes it will". If the OP wants a better answer I think he should reformulate his question. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Definitely, it will break in legacy browser. However I think one can use `postcss-css-variables` plugin to do the conversion. So that you can keep on using the CSS variable feature, but do not need to worry too much on legacy browser. When those legacy browsers fades out, you can just remove the plugin.

Checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-css-variables for details.

It also has a playground, which you can play around to see how it behaves.

For example,

```
    :root {
        --color-background: #ffaaaa;
        --font-color: #2222ff;
    }

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        :root {
            --color-background: #aaaaff;
            --font-color: #ffFF22;
        }
    }

    body {
        background-color: var(--color-background);
    }
    
    p {
        color: var(--font-color);
    }
```

will be convert to

```
    body {
        background-color: #ffaaaa;
    }

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

        body {
            background-color: #aaaaff;
        }
    }
    
    p {
        color: #2222ff;
    }
    
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

        p {
            color: #ffFF22;
        }
    }
```