# How Can I change color hex code to rgba using only CSS?

Tags: css, sass, colors

I have a small question that can cause me a problem, I have a project where I set a variable to a color using SASS, here is here is my SASS file __colors.scss :

```
$wild-watermelon: #f55463;
```

When I use this color, I do something like this :

```
.container {
    background-color: $wild-watermelon;
}
```

But I have something with I need to use the color but a little bit transparent, to do so, I have to use rgba(number, number, number, 0.75).

But I don't find this solution a propper one because if I want to change my theme coloring, I have to make changes in multiple files manually, not just one by changing my global variable.

I readed once a proposition, a solution let's say, suggesting that I use var function and I do something like this :

```
 .container {
     background-color: rgba(var($wild-watermelon),0.75);
 }
```

It did not work of course, that is why I am here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if it's only about backgorund here is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851246/8620333

Comment: no it's not only about background-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 $wild-watermelon: #f55463;

 .container {
   background-color: rgba($wild-watermelon, 0.75 );
 }
```

If you want to change the color, just change the hex code of the variable.

I would suggest to pick a more generic name though (e.g. $color-primary), just in case you do change the color scheme of your project in the future, so you don't have to change the variable name also. This way is more maintainable.